# Youtube Videos Title scraping - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, youtube

Don't know why I am getting error while fetching the video title element on Youtube. I tried every possible way. Please give a solution.

I tried this code :

```
list = []
video_title = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "yt-formatted-string")
for i in video_title:
    text_title = i.text
    list.extend(text_title)
print(list)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\scraping\Bot\Youtube\Y_data.py", line 25, in <module>
    text_title = i.text
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

List of videos title

Comment: Could you share your code

Comment: Otherwise just use the official [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to go through the video

```py
videos = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')
```

then you can scrap the title using

```py
title = video.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="video-title"]').text
```

value of XPATH and CLASS_NAME may be different in some case